# Angular 5, httpclient, Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: angular, cors, httpclient

I know there are a lot of simillar questions but I couldn't find any that could solve my problem.

I want to get access to my Binance account using their API.

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Here is simple function written using their example from docs:

```
postBinance() {
    const path = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order'
        + '?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559'
        + '&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71';

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .append('X-MBX-APIKEY', 'vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    const options = {
        headers: headers
    };

    return this.http.post(path, null, options);
}
```

Using that function cause error in firefox and chrome. 
Here is error from firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

And here from chrome:

> Failed to load https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

I have already installed extension for chrome "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *", but in this case it doesn't work.

What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you have added extension CORS and enable it. For reference: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

1. Create a file named as proxy.conf.json at the root of the project
2. Paste following in the file: 
   {
        "/api": {
        "target": “your API URL”,
        "secure": false
        }
   }
3. Run cmd as:- 
   ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json